# In JQuery, how to filter by both "button" and "not in class"?

Tags: jquery-selectors

In jQuery selector, I know hot select all Button:

```
$("input:button")
```

And how to not contain class

```
$("input:not(.class1)")
```

But how do you filter by both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input:button:not(.class1)")
```

FWIW, consider using `<button>` and not `<input type="button">` when it makes sense to do so...e.g., if your button input doesn't have a value, *why would it be an input element*?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()`

```
$("input[type='button']").filter(':not(.class1)')
```